# Web-app working perfectly on local-system and in unpredictable manner on the google-app-engine

Tags: ajax, jsp, google-app-engine, session, web-applications

I made this tictactoe web-app using eclipse as a google app engine app. It is working perfectly on the localhost and fast too. After deploying it, when I tested the live app, it is working unpredictably.

[**My Web-app**](http://unbeatablettt.appspot.com/)

The problem is moves are not being performed properly, computer is not making its moves sometimes. In my localhost they are accurately working.
Here I have used ajax for call after game start and after every move of user.
I have used session to maintain 'Game' object between subsequent ajax requests.
All my code is hosted here:

https://github.com/SaurabhGoyal/tictactoe

My question is **can someone tell me what the problem is or at-least tell me some way to debug it.**
Or tell me what code should I post here.

Because my tested app before deploying is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Problem,
I found the reason for unpredictable behaviour.
I was fetching game object from session, but after making changes in it, I was not updating the game object in session.